# TypeError: Cannot read property 'gaugeData2' of undefined at eval (dashboard.v1.vue?88bf:1465) in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am using PHP with a MySQL database to display data onto highcharts in vue.js. I define an array in data section of the page like this which will be used to display the chart data

```
data() {
return {
  gaugeData2: [],
}
```

I then use axios.get function to retrieve the data from the database like this -

```
 allRecords: function() {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost/contacts.php" + "?action=fetch-all")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      //var x = JSON.parse(response.data)
      var x = response.data
      console.log(typeof x)
      
      this.gaugeData2.push(x)
      console.log(this.gaugeData2)
      
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

When i try this i get an error in the console - "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'gaugeData2' of undefined
at eval (dashboard.v1.vue?88bf:1465)**"

I read somewhere online that data in vue.js returns type object and my function is returning a value of type 'number' and hence this error. I tried JSON.parse to convert it into an object type but it did not work. Could someone help me out, Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  //var x = JSON.parse(response.data)
  var x = response.data
  console.log(typeof x)
  
  this.gaugeData2.push(x)
  console.log(this.gaugeData2)
  
})
```

to this

```
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
  //var x = JSON.parse(response.data)
  var x = response.data
  console.log(typeof x)
  
  this.gaugeData2.push(x)
  console.log(this.gaugeData2)
  
})
```

Read more about [arrow function binding this](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256), or manually binding it.